# Two meshes close together are breaking apart in view and render. Possible fix or built-in feature?

Tags: mesh

this specific problem is something that I knew about for quite a long time but have been able to work around until now. 
[image]

There is a wall behind the set of bricks, and since both objects are very close to each other, (though not touching), the view presents a choppy and ripped up version of the mesh I need.

Is there a way to prevent this? In the settings of the camera or blender at all? Is it a built in function or is it something I can turn off?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This looks like [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). Where objects basically share the same space.

Comment: This is not built-in feature (nor it can be), it's a limitation (afaik in CG in general) of precision for the several faces occupying (nearly) the same place in the 3d space. It depends on clipping as well and as clipping differs for viewport and camera you need to adjust them accordingly (not to say moving meshes slightly away)

Comment: So it's impossible to prevent once I reach a certain distance away?

Comment: Hold on, I get it, I just had to set the minimum amount of clipping to 3. (My object space is very large, (Maximum clipping of 1000 units XD)) That seemed to work well enough.